# Why IntelliSense doesn't work as expected in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

While typing the following code snippet, I noticed that Intellisense didn't work as expected:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(sb))
{
    var name = prop.DisplayName;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", name);
}
```

In the foreach statement, if I start typing prop.Di, Intellisense completes as expexcted with prop.DisplayName. However, I use the var keyword instead of `PropertyDescriptor`, then I see only the method inherited from object.

As `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()` returns a collection of TypeDescriptor, I thought that Visual Studio would be able to infer the correct type for `prop`.

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GetProperties` returns a [`PropertyDescriptorCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptorcollection.aspx) which only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor>`. If you use `var`, the type of `prop` is inferred to be `object` not `PropertyDescriptor`.

Answer (score 4):

It returns `PropertyDescriptorCollection`, and the return type of `GetEnumerator` method of `PropertyDescriptorCollection` is `IEnumerator` (non-generic). So even you can write

```
foreach (int prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(sb))
```

And you won't get any exception in compile time,but at runtime you will get an `InvalidCastException`.

Here is an example that demonstrates the difference:

Normally, this is invalid:

```
foreach(string x in new List<int>())
```

Because `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.But if you wrap it with a class and implement non-generic `IEnumerable` interface:

```
class NonGenericCollection : IEnumerable
{
    public List<int> List { get; set; }


    public NonGenericCollection()
    {
        List = new List<int>();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return List.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

You can write any type you want and don't get any exceptions in compile time:

```
foreach(string x in new NonGenericCollection())
```

Because the return type is inferred as *object* and the actual type is not known until the run-time.

Comment: `foreach(string x in new List<int>())` is invalid because there isn't cast from int to string, not because `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Change `List<int>` to `List<object>` and the compiler has no objections.